# Tomcat returns some unknown welcome page

Tags: tomcat, welcome-file

I am deploying a web app. I have no welcome files defined in web.xml (in both conf/web.xml and application web.xml). I do not have an index.html/index.htm/index.jsp in root of application. Still when I access `http://localhost:8080` it shows some page.

I have enabled access logs, but I do not see any request for / in access logs.

Any idea what might have been happening? From where it would be getting the welcome page? Is there a way I can log the path of file being send as response?

Comment: What page is it showing? Any specific text?

Comment: @WillKeeling It seems the issue was with the browser cache. It used to show an old index.html specific to my project. It was showing it even after I deleted index.html from root of my application. After clearing cookies/cache it is giving expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the root cause, it was due to browser. I am getting expected page after clearing browser cookies/cache. I was using FireFox. The browser was showing some old cached page.

Answer (score 0):

Check that it's not the `index.jsp` page from the ROOT webapp (`TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.jsp`).

Navigating directly to `http://localhost:8080` without specifying the webapp name will normally take you into ROOT.

For me, that page looks like

[image: Root index page]

Comment: No it used to show some old index.html specific to my application which no longer exists. It seems, the browser cached the page. It gives expected behavior after clearing cookies/cache.